# Relative orbital energies of Mn and Ni

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, transition-metals, periodic-trends

In this MO diagram, why are the atomic Mn $3d$ orbitals higher in energy than the Ni $3d$ orbitals?

[image: ![Ni-Mn banding and antibonding states]

Comment: Those elements are in the same period, but nickel has a higher atomic number and therefore greater effective nuclear charge.

Comment: Higher effective nuclear charge means increased stabilization of electrons.